# Matlab findpeaks unable to detect peak

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a 1d signal with a very clear peak, which I wish to characterise. For this, Matlab recommends the `findpeak()` function. I used it, but it could not detect any peaks.

Can anyone tell me why the peak detection fails, and how I could correct this? Is it because of the slight asymmetry, or because of its location close to the origin?

[image: result]

Here is the signal:

```
-0.749429547824983,-1.48893649456578,-3.69142404184161,-5.90518397007934,-8.94050442864937,-13.9397113416771,-18.6485000060921,-26.171050819591,-33.8321611238473,-42.6887187100784,-52.7848046259627,-64.0885716722416,-76.4819754427361,-89.7534943093904,-103.596636684011,-117.616848525362,-137.728485864984,-149.968644032202,-165.760526765682,-173.438446162355,-177.794367330021,-180.665504657482,-181.587837865151,-182.05669036563,-181.953081445756,-181.224964655595,-179.466956009378,-174.935326783301,-166.108729320377,-154.8188727578,-138.989450390713,-124.745660884327,-110.75406648731,-97.5101283485409,-85.3020579114654,-75.9579975036876,-67.4601854156705,-61.2940646311251,-55.6332658221936,-50.4524017554082,-45.7226429946525,-41.4134661940384,-37.4939178270878,-33.9335009233627,-30.7027744357005,-27.7737375478043,-25.120055867709,-22.7171735026633,-20.5423444708846,-18.1299037240041,-16.0034032566806,-13.4349709052746,-11.2814814601965,-9.22383728236694,-7.54259823223305,-6.16891326304915,-5.04643005083767,-4.12908680572436,-3.3792629187093,-2.76624567764036,-2.26496715909135,-1.85496794618472,-1.51954915870186,-1.24507971658957,-1.02043099016049,-0.836515683557349,-0.685911850401105,-0.562556362193813,-0.461494999843215,-0.378678691801432,-0.31079735465677,-0.255144373245673,-0.209506048358245,-0.172071392676599,-0.141358513015601,-0.116154515064569,-0.0954664351129079,-0.0784811657953865,-0.0645327193959676,-0.053075478741892,-0.0436623352584338,-0.035926816959731,-0.0295684746597058,-0.0243409295220307,-0.0200420949390602,-0.0165061752797916,-0.0135971170520871,-0.0112032475556222,-0.00923288465794644,-0.00761074093974044,-0.00627497778144994,-0.00517479134910001,-0.00426843397916662,-0.00352159205421904,-0.00290605583052415,-0.00239862841900826,-0.00198023071526613,-0.00163516691682862,-0.00135052167802519,-0.00111566519662662,-0.000881935744953948,-0.000697915251838727,-0.000524637598946218,-0.000394567839006708,-0.000296885161988861,-0.00020976002143167,-0.000148545955794115,-9.72008185405489e-05,-6.36690385791491e-05,-4.17477119966825e-05,-2.74018483759325e-05,-1.8003902287259e-05,-1.18410413188178e-05,-7.7955452552938e-06,-5.13728164003599e-06,-3.38881214609516e-06,-2.2376175188872e-06,-1.47892273125427e-06,-9.78415790827604e-07,-6.47913246914071e-07,-4.29460109665109e-07,-2.84930223745026e-07,-1.89217408323062e-07,-1.25773079886823e-07,-8.36787965589242e-08,-5.57238587861215e-08,-3.71416697587417e-08,-2.47783039314225e-08,-1.6544922828963e-08,-1.10567854116822e-08,-7.39503946153151e-09,-4.94938072790637e-09,-3.31402364108024e-09,-2.2188483621877e-09,-1.48377653147047e-09,-9.88495439963603e-10,-6.52325826840569e-10,-4.20789022022039e-10,-2.56587161450693e-10,-1.50808306057169e-10,-6.34502662515917e-11,-3.11362883724889e-11
```

and here is the x-data:

```
0.7,0.700231481481481,0.700462962962963,0.700925925925926,0.701388888888889,0.701851851851852,0.702777777777778,0.703472222222222,0.704166666666667,0.704861111111111,0.705555555555555,0.70625,0.706944444444444,0.707638888888889,0.708333333333333,0.709027777777778,0.709722222222222,0.711111111111111,0.711805555555555,0.7125,0.713194444444444,0.713541666666667,0.713888888888889,0.71412037037037,0.714351851851852,0.714814814814815,0.715277777777778,0.715740740740741,0.716666666666667,0.718055555555556,0.719097222222222,0.720138888888889,0.721180555555555,0.722222222222222,0.723263888888889,0.724305555555556,0.725,0.725694444444444,0.726388888888889,0.727083333333333,0.727777777777778,0.728472222222222,0.729166666666667,0.729861111111111,0.730555555555556,0.73125,0.731944444444444,0.732638888888889,0.733333333333333,0.734027777777778,0.735069444444444,0.736111111111111,0.7375,0.738888888888889,0.740277777777778,0.741666666666667,0.743055555555555,0.744444444444444,0.745833333333333,0.747222222222222,0.748611111111111,0.75,0.751388888888889,0.752777777777778,0.754166666666667,0.755555555555556,0.756944444444444,0.758333333333333,0.759722222222222,0.761111111111111,0.7625,0.763888888888889,0.765277777777778,0.766666666666667,0.768055555555555,0.769444444444444,0.770833333333333,0.772222222222222,0.773611111111111,0.775,0.776388888888889,0.777777777777778,0.779166666666667,0.780555555555555,0.781944444444444,0.783333333333333,0.784722222222222,0.786111111111111,0.7875,0.788888888888889,0.790277777777778,0.791666666666667,0.793055555555555,0.794444444444444,0.795833333333333,0.797222222222222,0.798611111111111,0.8,0.801388888888889,0.802777777777778,0.804166666666667,0.80625,0.808333333333333,0.810416666666667,0.8125,0.814583333333333,0.817708333333333,0.820833333333333,0.823958333333333,0.827083333333333,0.830208333333333,0.833333333333333,0.836458333333333,0.839583333333333,0.842708333333333,0.845833333333333,0.848958333333333,0.852083333333333,0.855208333333333,0.858333333333333,0.861458333333333,0.864583333333333,0.867708333333333,0.870833333333333,0.873958333333333,0.877083333333333,0.880208333333333,0.883333333333333,0.886458333333333,0.889583333333333,0.892708333333333,0.895833333333333,0.898958333333333,0.902083333333333,0.905208333333333,0.908333333333333,0.911458333333333,0.914583333333333,0.917708333333333,0.920833333333333,0.922916666666667,0.925
```

I copy-pasted them from a comma-delimited .txt file.

Comment: I think it detects positive peaks. Have you tried giving it the negative of the signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the help you can see:

```
PKS = findpeaks(Y) finds local peaks in the data vector Y. A local peak
    is defined as a data sample which is either larger than the two
    neighboring samples or is equal to Inf.
```

So by default it is looking for a positive peak, you can supply the -ve of the signal and it will find it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `findpeaks()` only detects *maxima*. Stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the peak by fitting the posted data to a three-parameter Extreme Value peak equation, "y = a * exp(-exp(-((x-b)/c))-((x-b)/c)+1.0)", with parameter b as the peak at approximately x = 0.714. Fitted parameters of a = -1.7877846561352214E+02, b =  7.1375869130522429E-01, and c =  6.4029302224962413E-03 yielded RMSE = 2.64 and R-squared = 0.997.

[image: plot]